# HashSet storing Singleton object twice

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, singleton

I store a Singleton object through 10,000 threads in a HashSet (i.e. 10,000 times). Surprisingly sometimes HashSet can't recognize that Object is Singleton and stores the same object instance two times. And sometimes, it stores the object once but its size() method returns the value 2 or 3.

My Singleton Class is:-

```
public class Singleton {

  private Singleton() {

    System.out.println("Singleton--- It runs just once");

    }

   private static class StageSingletonHolder {

    static Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    }


   public static Singleton getInstance() {

    return StageSingletonHolder.instance;
  }


 }
```

The RunObject which provides run method for the Main Class' threads:-

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


 public class RunObject implements Runnable{
  Singleton singleton;
  public static Set<Singleton> set = new HashSet<Singleton>();


  public void run(){

      singleton = Singleton.getInstance();
      set.add(singleton);       
    }



    public int numberOfSingletons(){

    for(Singleton single:set){

        System.out.println(single);

        }

    System.out.println("set size : "+set.size());

   }

 }
```

My Main Class is:-

```
  public class MainObject {

   public static void main(String[] args){
   RunObject runObject = null;
   Thread t;
   int i = 0;
   while(i++ < 10000){
    runObject = new RunObject();
    t = new Thread(runObject);
    t.start();
    }

  }
 }
```

Here, in some cases, The same object is stored more than once.
I know that Singleton logic works correctly because its constructor runs just once. This is evident by its constructor printing the statement just once.

What could be the reason of this inconsistency?

Comment: Does your class `Singleton` implement the `hashCode()` (and `equals()`) method? Probably the hashcode of the singleton-instance changes over time

Comment: @MrD, Thanks for your reply. Sir, May you let me know why is it mandatory to implement hashCode and equals method? Why does the hashCode of singleton instance change over time?

Comment: The `hashCode()` method does not automatically change over time, if you didn't override it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HashSet` is not thread safe. You need to synchronize the adding or use an appropriate concurrent collection for storing the singleton.